# Getting error while uploading files to google drive in Delphi

Tags: delphi, google-drive-api, delphi-2010

I am trying to upload files to Google drive using RestAPI in Delphi. But unable to upload files into Drive.
Authentication to google drive succeeded but getting error while uploading files.
Below is the error message I am getting.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
var
  LURL: string;
  wv: Tfrm_OAuthWebForm;
  LToken: string;
   parents: TJSONArray;
  Folder: TJSONObject;
  upload_stream:TFileStream;
 local_filename : string;
 ttt: TJSONObject;
begin
  edt_GoogleTasks_AuthCode.Text := '';
  edt_GoogleTasks_AccessToken.Text := '';
  edt_GoogleTasks_RefreshToken.Text := '';

  /// step #1: get the auth-code
  LURL := 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth';
  LURL := LURL + '?response_type=' + URIEncode('code');
  LURL := LURL + '&client_id=' + URIEncode(edt_GoogleTasks_ClientID.Text);
  LURL := LURL + '&redirect_uri=' + URIEncode('urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob');
  LURL := LURL + '&scope=' + URIEncode('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tasks');
  // optional
  // LURL := LURL + '&login_hint=' + URIEncode('user@example.com');

  wv := Tfrm_OAuthWebForm.Create(self);
  try
    wv.OnTitleChanged := self.OAuth2_GoogleTasks_BrowserTitleChanged;
    wv.ShowModalWithURL(LURL);
  finally
    wv.Release;
  end;

  /// step #2: get the access-token

  ResetRESTComponentsToDefaults;

  RESTClient.BaseURL := 'https://accounts.google.com/';

  RESTRequest.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPOST;
  RESTRequest.Resource := 'o/oauth2/token';
  RESTRequest.Params.AddItem('code', edt_GoogleTasks_AuthCode.Text, TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
  RESTRequest.Params.AddItem('client_id', edt_GoogleTasks_ClientID.Text, TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
  RESTRequest.Params.AddItem('client_secret', edt_GoogleTasks_ClientSecret.Text, TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
  RESTRequest.Params.AddItem('redirect_uri', 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob', TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
  RESTRequest.Params.AddItem('grant_type', 'authorization_code', TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);

  RESTRequest.Execute;

  if RESTRequest.Response.GetSimpleValue('access_token', LToken) then
    // edt_GoogleTasks_AccessToken.Text := LToken;
    OAuth2_GoogleTasks.AccessToken := LToken;
  if RESTRequest.Response.GetSimpleValue('refresh_token', LToken) then
    // edt_GoogleTasks_RefreshToken.Text := LToken;
    OAuth2_GoogleTasks.RefreshToken := LToken;

    {$IF DEFINED(MsWindows)}
  local_filename :=  ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) +'Sanjeev.txt';
{$ENDIF}
 RESTResponseDataSetAdapter.AutoUpdate := false;
 RESTRequest.Params.Clear;
                               RESTRequest.ClearBody;
 //RESTRequest.Method:=rmpost;
//try
 RESTClient.BaseURL :=     'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?';



      upload_stream := TFileStream.Create(local_filename,fmOpenReadWrite);
  upload_stream.Position := 0;
RESTRequest.AddBody(upload_stream,     TRESTContentType.ctAPPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);

try
  RESTRequest.Execute;//Exception line
except
on e: Exception do
begin
  ShowMessage(e.Message);
   end;
       end;
  upload_stream.Free;
```

**Edit:**

Finally I was able to upload a file to google drive. I changed the api url which previously I set it as `LURL := LURL + '&scope=' + URIEncode('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tasks')`. I changed it to `LURL := LURL + '&scope=' + URIEncode('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive')` and now the file is getting uploaded properly.

Everything seemed good. But I noticed that the file is getting uploaded with untitled file name as in the below image.

[image]

Can some one suggest how to give a file name/ upload the file with the same name to google drive.

Comment: Have you done any debugging? Have you looked at the content of the request that you send?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I debugged and found that I missed adding a line. I added and now I am seeing other exception. I have edited the question with the same. Can you please suggest me what is causing this error?

Comment: Still, you need to debug this. Which line of code produces this error? What is the stack trace?

Comment: the line within try (added a comment 'Exception line' there) is causing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I was able to upload a file to google drive. I changed the api url which previously I set it as `LURL := LURL + '&scope=' + URIEncode('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tasks')`. I changed it to `LURL := LURL + '&scope=' + URIEncode('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive')` and now the file is getting uploaded properly.